# Selenium Webdriver - Java - Exception on trying to write data in Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, selenium

[Jar Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3o1p.png)

I'm trying to write a value to existing excel, While trying to run I'm getting below exception. Can someone guide please

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:106)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:342)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:285)
at samplescripts.WriteExcel.main(WriteExcel.java:19)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:213)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:132)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:56)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:99)
... 4 more
```

Below is the code that Is used

```
     package samplescripts;
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileInputStream;
     import java.io.FileOutputStream;
     import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
     import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
     public class WriteExcel {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     File src=new File("C:\\Selenium\\ExcelData\\TestData.xlsx");
     FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
     XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
     XSSFSheet sheet1=wb.getSheetAt(0);
     sheet1.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue("Pass");
     sheet1.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue("Fail");
     sheet1.getRow(2).createCell(2).setCellValue("14.12");
     FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(src);
     wb.write(fout);
     wb.close();
     }
     }
```

Comment: Did you google the exception? What did you find?

Comment: try to rename TestData.xlsx to TestData.zip and check consistency of that file (validate or unzip it)

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to read zip entry source at org.apache.poi.openxml4j

Your code appears to be correct, but as per the exception, it seems there is some problem in Apache POI jar that you are using, it might have been corrupted. Try to download the latest one, unzip it and use it again. Make sure you have added all these jar
[image]

Comment: I used the latest Apache POI jar but still I'm getting same issue. After I run the script excel sheet get's corrupted

Comment: Edited my answer, make sure you have added all those jar. Also check check your excel file that you are using whether you are able to open it normally

Comment: I'm using poi-3.15 jar, should I used 3.10 instead of 3.15. Please advise

Comment: Still getting same exception. I have attached Jar Files that I used as an attachment (Refer Jar Files)